# Sorting dictionary based on another dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I have two Python dictionaries -

```
dict1 = {'a' : [1, 2, 3], 'b' : [4, 5, 6], 'c' : [7, 8, 9]}
dict2 = {'a' : 30, 'b' : 75, 'c' : 15}
```

I want to sort `dict1` based on the values of `dict2`.
The final answer should be something like -

```
[['c', [7, 8, 9]], ['a', [1, 2, 3]], ['b', [4, 5, 6]]]
```

What is the most efficient way to solve this?

Comment: can you post your code, have you tried anything yet?

Comment: dicts in Python are not ordered. If you want an ordered dict you can use `OrderedDict` from `collections`. However, your final answer is actually a list.

Comment: ordinary `dict`s in Python have no order, so you cannot sort them. You must use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: yeah, but OP shows a list of lists, not a dict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah. Use sorted() and pass a "key" function that knows how to get the value to sort by. Something like:

```
sorted(dict1.items(), key=lambda kv: dict2[kv[0]])
```

Note that I leave it as a list of tuples. If you want an actual dictionary out of this, you'd have to use OrderedDict.

Comment: Added parens to lamba parameter. Note the "something like".

Comment: in that case you can "anonymize" your second parameter as it isn't used: `key=lambda (k, _): dict2[k]`

Comment: @DustinOprea. Please test your code properly. It currently raises a SyntaxError in python3 (which the OP is using).

Comment: @ekhumoro It was just an off-the-cuff suggestion. The approach is valid even if I mistyped stuff while just taking a moment to give him the strategy. Again, I said "something like this". Try it now.

Answer (score 2):

Note that your result is no longer a dict, but rather a list of lists, which is better if you want to sort it, since order in dicts isn't guaranteed/implementation detail

I would sort the items according to the value of the key in the other dictionary, and convert the tuples that `items` yield to 2-elements `list`:

```
dict1 = {'a' : [1, 2, 3], 'b' : [4, 5, 6], 'c' : [7, 8, 9]}
dict2 = {'a' : 30, 'b' : 75, 'c' : 15}

print([list(x) for x in sorted(dict1.items(),key = lambda x : dict2[x[0]])])
```

result:

```
[['c', [7, 8, 9]], ['a', [1, 2, 3]], ['b', [4, 5, 6]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
dict1 = {'a' : [1, 2, 3], 'b' : [4, 5, 6], 'c' : [7, 8, 9]}
dict2 = {'a' : 30, 'b' : 75, 'c' : 15}
new_data = list(map(list, sorted(dict1.items(), key=lambda x:dict2[x[0]])))
```

Output:

```
[['c', [7, 8, 9]], ['a', [1, 2, 3]], ['b', [4, 5, 6]]]
```

Comment: I'd probably choose a list comprehension instead of `list(map(…))`, perhaps: `[[k, dict1[k]] for k in  sorted(dict1.keys(), key=lambda x:dict2[x])]`.